# Popcornjs password protected vimeo video - events not fired

Tags: javascript, video, dom-events, vimeo, popcornjs

I am using Popcorn.js to pull in videos from both YouTube and Vimeo with the `Popcorn.smart` player.

This works fine as expected until pulling in a password protected Vimeo video.

When the Vimeo video is password protected the player is created but with Vimeo's password overlay (as you'd want).  However no events are fired either before or after entering the password.

I have tried most events and none of them fire.

I need access to the video duration before the rest of my UI can continue so if anyone has any ideas that would be great.

As an example I have [Big Buck Bunny](http://jsfiddle.net/rockingskier/7hXCd/5/) hidden behind a password.

1. Enter password: **hippo**
2. See no events firing
3. Press play
4. Still no events

1. Re-run fiddle
2. See 'durationchange' is fired
3. Press play
4. Lots of 'timeupdate' events

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for uploading password protected test video. +1 :)